# Android check if multiple strings are not empty

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a form and I put the forms data in an intent and then start a new activity and send the data with the intent, but I wanna do a check if the strings are empty I should display and error message. If the strings are not empty the activity can be started.

I've tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be working. If the field is empty it just starts the other activity
(I've tried with only 1 field for now, because I don't know how to to it for multiple fields)

```
    //getting the field values
    String firstname = editTextFirstname.getText().toString();
    String lastname = editTextLastname.getText().toString();
    String amount = editTextBedrag.getText().toString();
    String timespan = spinnerPeriode.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String iban = editTextIBAN.getText().toString();

    if(firstname != null) {
        //putting data in the intent
        intent.putExtra(FIRSTNAME, firstname);
        intent.putExtra(LASTNAME, lastname);
        intent.putExtra(AMOUNT, amount);
        intent.putExtra(TIMESPAN, timespan);
        intent.putExtra(IBAN, iban);

        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Oops, you forgot to fill in some fields!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if(firstname != null)
```

to

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(firstname) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(lastname) &&
     !TextUtils.isEmpty(amount) &&!TextUtils.isEmpty(timespan) &&
     !TextUtils.isEmpty(iban))
```

Comment: this answer is not correct, if you blank a field and run this code result is not correct

Answer (score 7):

A cleaner way to do this is

```
public static boolean isAnyStringNullOrEmpty(String... strings) {
    for (String s : strings)
        if (s == null || s.isEmpty())
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```
if (isAnyStringNullOrEmpty(firstname, lastname, amount, timespan, iban)) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Oops, you forgot to fill in some fields!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using apache commons, we can do this as:

```
boolean valid = StringUtils.isNoneEmpty(firstname, lastname, amount, timespan, iban)
```

Comment: Or I would say StringUtils#isNoneBlank.  isNoneEmpty() considers space as a non-empty value where isNoneBlank() will say it's empty.

Comment: I appreciate you pointing it out in the comments- However, the question specifically asks for empty. Thankyou for your input though.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 + Apache Commons Lang only:

```
String firstname = editTextFirstname.getText().toString();
String lastname = editTextLastname.getText().toString();
String amount = editTextBedrag.getText().toString();
String timespan = spinnerPeriode.getSelectedItem().toString();
String iban = editTextIBAN.getText().toString();


boolean valid =  Stream.of(firstname, lastname, amount, timespan, iban)
                       .allMatch(StringUtils::isNotBlank);
```

Comment: what if i am gettng multiple strings from server and saving it to string now some of have a value but some of them are empty how to check which are empty and which have some values  + how to set the values which are not empty to some specif fields??

Answer (score 0):

```
if(firstname != null && lastname != null && amount != null && timespan != null
 && iban != null & firstname.trim().isEmpty() && !lastname.trim().isEmpty() &&
 !amount .trim().isEmpty() && !timespan.trim().isEmpty() && !iban.trim().isEmpty())
```

Comment: and what if it get any string not equal to null then how to get the value ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Java Stream API:

```
private boolean anyBlank(String...strings) {
   return Stream.of(strings).anyMatch(string -> isBlank(string));
}
```